# Different radio button selection for different questions

Tags: php, html

I want to generate a question paper by extracting the questions and its options from the database.AS there are 3 questions, 15 options ,5 For each question, I am able to select one option only out of 15. I have attached the code below and image output also

[image]

```
<?php
for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++)
    $s = "select OPTION1,OPTION2,OPTION3,OPTION4,OPTION5,CORRECT_ANSWER from T_QUESTIONS where QUES_NO='$i'";
          $result=mysqli_query($conn,$s);
            if(!mysqli_query($conn,$s))
                echo mysqli_error($conn);
            else
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {?>

                            <form action = "CHECK.php" method="POST">
                        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="<?php $row['OPTION1']; ?>" /> <?php echo $row['OPTION1']."<br>"; ?>
                        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="<?php $row['OPTION2']; ?>" /> <?php echo $row['OPTION2']."<br>"; ?>
                        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="<?php $row['OPTION3']; ?>" /> <?php echo $row['OPTION3']."<br>"; ?>
                        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="<?php $row['OPTION4']; ?>" /> <?php echo $row['OPTION4']."<br>"; ?>
                        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="<?php $row['OPTION5']; ?>" /> <?php echo $row['OPTION5']."<br>"; ?>
                        <br>


        <?php         
        }       
        }

        ?>
```

Comment: In your radio-values, you have `<?php $row['OPTION5']; ?>`, you need to `echo` those first. `<?php echo $row['OPTION5']; ?>`

Comment: Radio `name` should be different according to question

Comment: You don't have an ending `</form>` tag. And you re-open a form within each loop.

Comment: You have to put <form> tag out side of the loop. you can check my answer

Comment: You have to give separate name to set of radio buttons of each question. You can use question id in name For example. Question1: answer_1, answer_1,..answer_1. Question2: answer_2,answer_2,...answer_2. And also use form tag outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action = "CHECK.php" method="POST">
<?php
for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++) { ?>
    <label>Question</label>
    <input type="radio" name="choice<?php echo $i?>" value="a" /> 1
    <input type="radio" name="choice<?php echo $i?>" value="b" /> 1
    <input type="radio" name="choice<?php echo $i?>" value="c" /> 1
    <input type="radio" name="choice<?php echo $i?>" value="d" /> 1
    <input type="radio" name="choice<?php echo $i?>" value="e" /> 1
    <br>
<?php }  ?>
</form>
```

Comment: That would mean you can select more than 1 radio.

Comment: For each question 1 radio

Comment: You can name all the radio buttons differently for each question, but for the *same* question they need to have the same name. Otherwise you can select multiple answers to the same question (which might be fine, but then use a checkbox and not a radio).

Comment: Yes I meant for each question 1 radio needs to be selected, so name of all the radios for single question should be same. And that is what I have shown - `choice1` will be the name attribute for all radios in case of first question, `choice2` for 2nd and `choice3` for 3rd.

Comment: But it is enabling multiselect property.I want one radio button selection per question

Comment: HOW TO ADD UNSELECT FEATURE

Comment: Try out with help of this, it works: I have added it in my answer as well
`<form action = "CHECK.php" method="POST">
<?php
for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++) { ?>
 <label>Question</label>
 <input type="radio" name="choice<?php echo $i?>" value="a" /> 1
 <input type="radio" name="choice<?php echo $i?>" value="b" /> 1
 <input type="radio" name="choice<?php echo $i?>" value="c" /> 1
 <input type="radio" name="choice<?php echo $i?>" value="d" /> 1
 <input type="radio" name="choice<?php echo $i?>" value="e" /> 1
 <br>
<?php }  ?>
</form>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it. You have to put `<form>` tag out side of the loop and You have to set different `name` attribut for `radio` button :

```
    <form action = "CHECK.php" method="POST">
    <?php
    for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++)
        $s = "select OPTION1,OPTION2,OPTION3,OPTION4,OPTION5,CORRECT_ANSWER from T_QUESTIONS where QUES_NO='$i'";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$s);
        if(!mysqli_query($conn,$s))
            echo mysqli_error($conn);
        else
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {?>


                    <input type="radio" name="choice<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['OPTION1']; ?>" /> <?php echo $row['OPTION1']."<br>"; ?>
                    <input type="radio" name="choice<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['OPTION2']; ?>" /> <?php echo $row['OPTION2']."<br>"; ?>
                    <input type="radio" name="choice<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['OPTION3']; ?>" /> <?php echo $row['OPTION3']."<br>"; ?>
                    <input type="radio" name="choice<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['OPTION4']; ?>" /> <?php echo $row['OPTION4']."<br>"; ?>
                    <input type="radio" name="choice<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['OPTION5']; ?>" /> <?php echo $row['OPTION5']."<br>"; ?>
                    <br>


    <?php         
    }       
    }

    ?>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php   for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++)
            {?>
<form action = "CHECK.php" method="POST">
<?php

        $s = "select OPTION1,OPTION2,OPTION3,OPTION4,OPTION5,CORRECT_ANSWER from T_QUESTIONS where QUES_NO='$i'";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$s);
        if(!mysqli_query($conn,$s))
            echo mysqli_error($conn);
        else
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {?>


                    <input type="radio" name="choice<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['OPTION1']; ?>" /> <?php echo $row['OPTION1']."<br>"; ?>
                    <input type="radio" name="choice<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['OPTION2']; ?>" /> <?php echo $row['OPTION2']."<br>"; ?>
                    <input type="radio" name="choice<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['OPTION3']; ?>" /> <?php echo $row['OPTION3']."<br>"; ?>
                    <input type="radio" name="choice<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['OPTION4']; ?>" /> <?php echo $row['OPTION4']."<br>"; ?>
                    <input type="radio" name="choice<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['OPTION5']; ?>" /> <?php echo $row['OPTION5']."<br>"; ?>
                    <br>


    <?php         
    }       
    }
    ?>
    </form>
```